# Bar Chart D3.js Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, bar-chart

I am trying to implement Mbostock's Bar Chart (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304), literally copy-pasting it here: http://bl.ocks.org/jcahan/6befca00bfaab1e731b6. However, as you can see by clicking the link, the graph does not properly load. The Console identifies the errors to be:

```
Error: Invalid Value for <rect> attribute y = "NaN"
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN"
```

I do not see how either of our codes are different. I suspect that there is the chance that I did not properly create the data.tsv file within the gist, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: The header of your TSV seems to be separated by two spaces instead of a tab.

Comment: hi @LarsKotthoff, I attempted to use a "tab," but it is automatically set for two spaces. How would you recommend I fix this with spaces?

Comment: That depends entirely on the text editor you're using. You could however simply use the TSV file from the example as-is.

Comment: I copy-pasted what he had from his gist to mine to test it.

Comment: You could just download the TSV file.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. However, even after doing that, nothing has changed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33155/discussion-between-jsc123-and-lars-kotthoff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copied the TSV file, the tab separating the two headers was replaced by two spaces. After you've fixed that, you need to replace that file in your Gist.